# Using netsh add DNS then Error Element not found

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

I am trying to run a netsh command to add a second dns address

```
netsh interface ip add dns name="Local Area Connection" 75.75.75.75
```

but when I execute the command I get an error

```
Element not found.
```

I know that this dns is available because when I dhcp it is in my DNS address list.

```
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.100.11
                                       75.75.75.75
```

How do I fix this error to be able to add my second dns?

Comment: Try `netsh interface ipv4 add dns "Local Area Connection" 75.75.75.75 index=2`

Comment: It could be barking about the Network Name.  Try using the IDx number instead.

Comment: I tried index=2 but it said that the command wasn't recognized. How do I find its IDx number?

Comment: List the interfaces. `netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces`

Comment: That did it. Any idea why it wouldn't work with the name?

Comment: No clue.  I found it on a Microsoft forum post when I google searched **netsh element not found**. It was literally the first link Google gave me.

Comment: Can you try to run cmd or your script with administrator privileges and see what happens? I've read somewhere that this requires admin privileges.